# gulp / gulp-nodemon - Nodemon never starts

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am trying to set up a `serve` task that will do the following:

1. Call a `watch` task to watch for any source changes. ( the watch task calls a `build` task that builds the app into a "build" folder )
2. Start the app using Nodemon ( gulp-nodemon )
3. If a source change happens - rebuild the app and restart nodemon

So far I've written the following tasks:

```
gulp.task('build', gulp.series(['lint'], () => {
    del.sync(['./build/**/*.*']);
    const tsCompile = gulp.src('./src/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(gulpSourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(project());

    return tsCompile.js.pipe(gulpSourcemaps.write({
        sourceRoot: file => path.relative(path.join(file.cwd, file.path), file.base)
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
}));

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series(['build'], () => {
    gulp.watch('./src/**/*.ts', gulp.series(['build']));
}));

gulp.task('serve', gulp.series(['watch'], () => {
    return gulpNodemon({
        script: './build/index.js',
        watch: './build/'
    });
}));
```

The current behavior of the tasks is:

1. I start the application by typing `gulp serve`
2. The `watch` tasks is called and it works as expected
3. Nodemon does not start and the process is stuck at the `watch` task. If I change any of the source code, the `watch` task will be called.

Basically, Nodemon does not start and only the `watch` task is working.

I am not able to figure out why the following behavior happens and I want to ask if anyone knows what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use are running your `watch` task in **series**.

However, the `watch` task does not end so **nodemon** never starts.

Try using `gulp.parallel()` instead of `gulp.series()`:

```
gulp.task('serve', gulp.parallel('watch', () => {
  return gulpNodemon({
    script: './build/index.js',
    watch: './build/'
  });
}));
```

Hopefully this should solve your problem.